# Pentaho Report Designer "text to columns"

Tags: split, field, pentaho, transformation

I have a table (in a postgresql database) with a column of "metadata" delimited by comma, semicolon and hyphen. I need to split that column the same way as Excel's "text to columns" option. Can anyone tell me if is that possible in PRD?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is.
I would like to answer with just "It is", but, if Pentaho Report Designer can't do it, Pentaho Data Integration can, i'd say in your case you would use PDI for data staging, and use that treated data in PRD.

Comment: Thank you! I'm downloading PDI right now, like you said, it is the right tool for this.